# Intersecting family of infinite sets

Tags: combinatorics

An intersecting family of sets is a collection of sets such that every two sets intersect.

There are many results about the the intersecting family of $[n]=\{1,\cdots,n\}$. However I am eager to know that "Is there any reference about the intersecting family of infinite sets?".
Thanks in advance

Comment: A useful search phrase is "pairwise intersecting", or "pairwise intersection". For example, see [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22pairwise+intersection%22+%22infinite+family%22+sets&filter=0). Also, maybe something of interest will be among [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=almost+finite+intersection+sets+site:math.stackexchange.com), and possibly also among [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=sets+combinatorics+infinite+intersection+site%3Amath.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you very much